# How to Find the Max Plot of Land From a 2D Array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Sorry if the title was a little confusing, I didn't know what to call it. However, I'm still new to programming and I'm stuck on this coding problem that I just have no idea where to start.

Here is the summarized version of the problem:

I have a randomized plot of land, lets just call the variables x and y. This plot of land is a 2D array of all numbers that can be negative or positive. Now, there will be another, smaller plot of randomized numbers, lets call them width, height. With these new variables I need to find the greatest number from the x,y array that is width, height in size.

All numbers will be valid integers.

`x ≥ width > 0` 
`y ≥ height > 0`

I will need to output the largest sum of land in the x y plot that is width, height in size.

Here is an example

```
3 - randomly picked y value
4 - randomly picked x value
2 - randomly picked height
1 - randomly picked width
1 2 3 4
-1 0 -1 9
-4 1 -2 7
```

Now, you can see from the example that the output will be 16, because the biggest 1x2 plot in the 4x3 plot is 16. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction and give me tips on where to start. I have tried researching this, but it has led nowhere because I have no idea what to look up.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but it seems like you could iterate through all the possible (valid) sizes (and their positions) and select the biggest one. i.e. a brute-force search of all the possibilities.

Comment: That is what I was considering doing, but I have absolutely no idea how I would look through the array depending on randomized width and height variables. I just dont know what I should look up. Everything I've searched has given me nothing valuable

Comment: Well, given a  specific size and the corner position of an area, you should be able to loop through all the possible x, y coordinate pairs that are within the area. Now hopefully you have some idea…

Comment: Yes, that does clear things up for me. Thank you.

Comment: Good, once you have something working, there _may_ be ways to speed things up if it's taking too long — depending on whether there's any additional information that would allow certain area & position combinations to be skipped, for example.

Comment: One other comment. If you ask furhter questions about this subject, avoid using the word "plot" which usually means some sort of graphic with respect to programming and computers. Perhaps something like "lot", "parcel", or  "tract" of land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summed-area table seems to be an interesting way to tackle this problem. If I'm not mistaken such an algorithm would be linear in the number of cells (`x*y`).

The basic idea of a summed-area table is that the sum of a subparcel can be calculated by adding the values for two corners and subtracting the values of the opposite corners, as explained in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table).

Numpy's `cumsum` helps to quickly create the summed-area table. Maybe there is also a numpy way to calculate the areas?

Here's my sample code (note that numpy first indexes the vertical direction, and then the horizontal). The tests inside the loop could be skipped if we added an extra row and extra column of zeros (but would make the code slightly more difficult to understand).

```py
import numpy as np

def find_highest_area_sum(parcel, x, y, width, height):
    sums = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(parcel, axis=0), axis=1)
    areas = np.zeros((y - height + 1, x - width + 1), dtype=sums.dtype)

    print("Given parcel:")
    print(parcel)
    print("Cumulative area sums:")
    print(sums)
    for i in range(x - width + 1):
        for j in range(y - height + 1):
            areas[j, i] = sums[j + height - 1, i + width - 1]
            if i > 0:
                areas[j, i] -= sums[j + height - 1, i - 1]
            if j > 0:
                areas[j, i] -= sums[j - 1, i + width - 1]
            if i > 0 and j > 0:
                areas[j, i] += sums[j - 1, i - 1]
    print("Areas of each subparcel:")
    print(areas)
    ind_highest = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(areas), areas.shape)
    print(f'The highest area sum is {areas[ind_highest]} at pos ({ind_highest[1]}, {ind_highest[0]}) to pos ({ind_highest[1] + width - 1}, {ind_highest[0] + height - 1}) ')

x, y = 4, 3
width, height = 1, 2
parcel = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [-1, 0, -1, 9],
                   [-4, 1, -2, 7]])
find_highest_area_sum(parcel, x, y, width=1, height=2)

x = 12
y = 20
parcel = np.random.randint(-10, 20, (y, x))
find_highest_area_sum(parcel, x, y, width=10, height=12)
```

Output of the first part:

```
Given parcel:
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [-1  0 -1  9]
 [-4  1 -2  7]]
Cumulative area sums:
[[ 1  3  6 10]
 [ 0  2  4 17]
 [-4 -1 -1 19]]
Areas of each subparcel:
[[ 0  2  2 13]
 [-5  1 -3 16]]
The highest area sum is 16 at pos (3, 1) to pos (3, 2)
```

Comment: Oh, yes for sure. Haven't been able to check since yesterday. I'll mark this as correct.